# iphone:Is that possible to create email button in HTML for eBook App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, webview

I am working on eBook app.In that i want to put email button to each chapters.Books are in HTML and i am loading that html page into webView.
Now is that any way to create Email button in HTML and get action of that button into objective-c?
Or is there any way to send contents of book chapters?

Comment: You can add the email button in a navigation bar or something, it's like that in tones of e book apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use javascript.

```
function drawButton(code){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var frame=document.createElement("div");
    var link=document.createElement("a");
    var image=document.createElement("img");

    image.src="btn-email.png";
    link.appendChild(image);
    link.href=sendmail(code);
    frame.appendChild(link);
    body.appendChild(frame);
```

}

this will draw the email button in your html document and you can call it from Obj C by using the stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString UIWebView method. In this example, I pass the variable "code", which is the primary key of an element in the core database. the href gets created through the function sendmail( ... ) which looks like this (in my code) and uses again "code" to create an unique link.

```
function sendmail(code){
    var scheme="mail:"+code;
    return scheme;
}
```

this will create a custom scheme which will get sent to the UIWebView in your application when a user taps on it. with the delegate method webViewShouldLoadRequest: you can capture that scheme and use the information in it.

code can be the unique id of a book in your database or s.th. When the user pressed on the mail button, mail:code_of_book gets send and you can use that code than to open the mail application with the right book attached. its pretty easy actually and quite convenient.

Check my blog for more information about that, i wrote a week ago 2 tutorials about using javascript in your web view and how to communicate with Obj C.

http://howtomakeitinamsterdam.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

Set a delegate on the UIWebView and Implement the webview:shouldStartLoadingWithRequest:navigationOptions method. Within this method you can query the request URL schema to implement different behaviour for the mailto: scheme - and then use mailto: links in your HTML source. For example you might want to do [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:...] to open the internal mail.app (haven't tested this but am 90% sure it will work).